# How to return just a specific part of the regex?

Tags: python, regex

```
import re

url = 'http://xxxxx.com/detail/028QCQZ?things_here'
re.search("detail/([A-Z0-9]+)\?", url).group()
```

returns :

```
'detail/028QCQZ?'
```

I thought that parenthesis were used in regular expressions to specify which part of the string to return.

I'd like to get only the code : **028QCQZ**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use 1st captured group like this:

```
re.search("detail/([A-Z0-9]+)\?", url).group(1)
//=> 028QCQZ
```

If you use **lookarounds** then you can use `group()` like this:

```
re.search(r"(?<=detail/)[A-Z0-9]+(?=\?)", url).group()
//=> 028QCQZ
```

Comment: Will do, I just need 10 more minutes as the website won't let me accept the answer before. Also thanks for the edit, nice addition.